# Change table on runtime - Spring API Rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-rest

Now, I have the next entity. This one is the ***m1*** table of my database.

```
@Entity(name = "m1")
@Data
public class Information {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String date;
    private Double weight_1;
    private Double weight_2;
    private Double weight_3;
    private Double weight_4;
    private int working;

}
```

So, when I do some call to the APIRest it returns me the information corresponding to the ***m1*** table. The controller that I have is the next (simple controller that returns all the information):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/information")
public class InformationController {

    @Autowired
    private InformationRepository repository;

    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public @ResponseBody List<Information> getAllInformations() {
        // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**The question is:** There is any way to change the name of the ***m1*** on runtime. For example can I put the name of the table in the call path and in the API Rest take it?

Maybe this is impossible and I am doing it the bad way I do not know.

**EDIT:** I mean, can I change the table that the API Rest is taking the data by putting the table that I want in the url/path that I call. For example: in my case the default table/entity that the APIRest take the data is ***m1***, so can I call http://localhost:8080/information/especifictable/all/ where especific table is the table that I want the recieve the data of the database and in the API Rest take that url parameter and change the default ***m1*** with the ***especifictable***.

I do not know if I have explained it well, I do not know how to explain it well.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by saying 'There is any way to change the name of the m1 on runtime' ?

Comment: I edit my question, I don't if now is more clear or not. I'm sorry I don't know how to explain it more clear.

Comment: why don't you want to create just a yet another entity?

Comment: yes that can be an option, but I want to know if this is possible or is an impossible way. Thank you for the comment

Comment: Again even after editing the question is still quite not right. How do you expect to retrieve data from another table, if that table does not exist?

Comment: @Aris The table that I want to take the information exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a design would only make sense, if there are two tables in DB, which look the same. if that is the case there is something wrong with your DB design.

Basically it is not possible, to the best of my knowledge.